# R Studio aborts after loading libraries, base R throws error

Tags: r, macos, path, libraries

I have not used R on my Mac in a few weeks, and now I am experiencing an issue where RStudio aborts my session immediately when trying to load any packages. When trying to load packages using base R, I get this error:

```
> library(dplyr)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dplyr’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/User/Rlibs/vctrs/libs/vctrs.so':
  dlopen(/Users/User/Rlibs/vctrs/libs/vctrs.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib'
  Referenced from: '/Users/User/Rlibs/vctrs/libs/vctrs.so'
  Reason: tried: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libR.dylib' (no such file)
```

It seems like R is not looking in the correct location to find my libraries. I have checked the location using:

```
.libPaths()
```

which reports back two directories. One user-specific path `[1] "/Users/User/Rlibs"` and one system-wide path `[2] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library"`. The user-specific path contains all of the packages I have previously installed, while the system-wide path contains only a small subset of R packages.

I have already tried reinstalling both RStudio and R.

How can I fix this to prevent RStudio from aborting my session?

Comment: Try `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)`.

Comment: `install.packages("vctrs")` might remove this specific error, though there might be some more coming

Answer (score 0):

Per @Roland, `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)` worked.